# grok pattern to extract errors

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok

I want to extract the logs that have ERROR messages along with the time stamp. Below is the sample log, can someone help me with grok patterns?

```
26.02.2016 20:46:24.236 *ERROR* [000.000.0.000 [1456537583643] GET /content/client-name/secure/dashboard.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource Paragraph, path=/content/client-name/secure/jcr:content/iparheader/mercerbbctopnavigati, type=client-uk/components/common/mercerBBCTopNavigation, cssClass=default, column=0/0, diffInfo=[null], resource=[JcrNodeResource, type=client-uk/components/common/mercerBBCTopNavigation, superType=null, path=/content/client-name/secure/jcr:content/iparheader/mercerbbctopnavigati]
26.02.2016 20:46:24.237 *INFO* [000.000.0.000 [1456537583643] GET /content/client-name/secure/dashboard.html HTTP/1.1] com.client.uk.utilities.CommonUtil Attempting to fetch configurations. Entered getConfiguration() block
26.02.2016 20:46:24.238 *INFO* [000.000.0.000 [1456537583643] GET /content/client-name/secure/dashboard.html HTTP/1.1] com.client.uk.taglibs.CommonTaglib linksList is[[Home, /content/client-name/secure/dashboard, , /content/dam/client/harmonise/logos/logo-client.png], [Health, /content/client-name/secure/health/health-summary, , /content/dam/client/harmonise/logos/logo-client.png], [Protection, /content/client-name/secure/life-sandbox], [Pension, /content/client-name/secure/pension-sandbox, , /content/dam/client/harmonise/logos/logo-client.png], [Finances, /content/client-name/secure/my-finance], [Articles & Videos, /content/client-name/secure/article-catalogue-page], [Profile, /content/client-name/secure/myprofile], [Help & Support, /content/client-name/secure/help-contact]]
26.02.2016 20:46:24.244 *INFO* [000.000.0.000 [1456537583643] GET /content/client-name/secure/dashboard.html HTTP/1.1] com.client.uk.utilities.CommonUtil >> Entry CommonUtil.getEncrytedUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} [(?[^]]+)] %{LOGLEVEL:severity} ((?[^]]+)) %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]